# How do I cause or create an invalid memory reference in Python on purpose?

Tags: python

How do I cause or create an invalid memory reference in Python on purpose?

This is a bit of a bar-bet. I'm told it can't be done. I don't believe that.

Comment: You create a python module in C that has a null dereference built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a module in C:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] =
{
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    (void)Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
    int* invalidptr = NULL;
    *invalidptr = 42;
}
```

And then from python:

```
import spam
```

Comment: I'd consider this more of a cheat the using ctypes.  This requires code to be written in C, where as ctypes uses only python code.

Comment: At no point did his questions specify "pure python". Besides, ctypes is a C module no matter how you cut it, so it's really 6 of 1, a half dozen of the other. Mine requires fewer lines of python :P

Comment: If I had made the bet, I wouldn't consider extending the language a valid means of winning the bet.  But then again, it really all depends on how you look at it.  My point, I suppose, is that I don't think your wrong, I just have a different way of looking at it.

Comment: @Chris So which is the dangling pointer here? How can i see where it is refering too?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)(ctypes.c_int())
>>> p[100000000]
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Sweet. That sounds like the answer.

Comment: @jcolebrand: It's a bit of cheating, though.  Usually, it's considered a bug in Python or its extensions if pure Python code can make the interpreter crash. `ctypes` is always quoted as an exception -- it's meant to give low-level access and can't be safe.

Comment: like I said, this was a bit of a bar bet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *
a = cast(0x1000, POINTER(c_int))
print a.contents
```